# Why do we set $system_path in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, lampp

I'm using XAMPP on Linux, so I moved the folder CodeIgniter-3.0.1 inside htdocs.

Below is the directory.

`/opt/lampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter-3.0.1`

On the User Guide, they wrote...

> After moving them, open your main index.php file and set the $system_path,
>   $application_folder and $view_folder variables, preferably with a full path, e.g. ‘/www/MyUser/system’.

1. What ***full path*** are they mentioning about?
2. Why we do that step?
3. ...and in my case, how will mine look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system_path is the location of the system folder within the CodeIgniter framework.  It needs to be set so that CodeIgniter knows where to look for its inner workings.  They say to use a full path (as in path from the root of the file system) so there's less issues when moving systems around which rely on that core system folder (see the next paragraph)

By setting this, it means that you can configure multiple CodeIgniter applications to all use the same core framework, and therefore only need to upgrade the core in one place.

In your case, based on the information provided, it will be `/opt/lampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter-3.0.1/system`

Comment: Wow, very well described! Thanks Captain Gabe!